# odoo 10 Many2many field in calendar view

Tags: odoo-10

I created a many2many field in odoo, but when I view it in the calendar view it displays the id but I want display name.

[image]

The field definition is:

```
doctor = fields.Many2many('crm.account.doctor.line',
                          'crm_account_doctor_name',
                          'doctor_name','id', required=True)
```

The XML:

```
<record id="doctor_calender" model="ir.ui.view"> 
  <field name="model">plan.new</field> 
  <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
    <calendar color="state" date_start="date" mode="month" quick_add="False" > 
      <field name="doctor" write_model="crm.account.doctor.line" write_field="doctor" avatar_model="crm.account.doctor.line"/> 
    </calendar> 
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Could you provide code samples or say what you've tried?

Comment: it is many2many field                                                                                 doctor = fields.Many2many('crm.account.doctor.line','crm_account_doctor_name','doctor_name','id', required=True)

Comment: my xml                                                                                                       <record id="doctor_calender" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="model">plan.new</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <calendar color="state" date_start="date" mode="month" quick_add="False" >
           <field name="doctor" write_model="crm.account.doctor.line" write_field="doctor" avatar_model="crm.account.doctor.line"/>

        </calendar>
         </field></record>

Comment: i want view name of doctor in calendar view but it view id of doctor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a good way to do what you're asking for.  What I would do is define a computed field with the display string you're looking for and use that in the view.

```
display_doctor = fields.Char(string='Display String for doctor field',
                             compute='_compute_display_doctor')

def _compute_display_doctor(self):
   '''
   Compute the display string for the doctor field
   '''
   for record in self:
     display_str = ','.join(record.doctor.mapped('name'))
     record.display_doctor = display_str
```

Then in the xml you can use that field instead of the `many2many` version.